# How to update the value of a textarea (ASP.NET Core MVC)

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

To make it simple:

This is my ServiceClass:

```
public class ServiceClass
{
        public string Request {get; set;}
        //other logic
        
        private void ExecuteCommand()
        {
            Request = "Some Text";
        }

}
```

My HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        [BindProperty]
        public ServiceClassModel ServiceClass { get; set; }

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {

            return View();
        }

        
}
```

I have a ServiceClassModel:

```
public class ServiceClassModel
{
    public string Request { get; set; }
    public string Response { get; set; }
    
    public ServiceClass Logic { get; set; }

}
```

And I have an IndexView with a TextArea:

```
<textarea id="story" name="story"
              rows="9" cols="80" style="margin-left: 10px; resize: none; margin-top: 10px">Here I want to update the text
```

**Now to my question:** I programmed a speech recognition application. There is a property called Request where my speech request is stored in the ServiceClass. I want every time when the method `ExecuteCommand();` is called to update the textarea in the index view. What is the best way to do it?

Using ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: Where you will call the `ExecuteCommand` method?

Comment: The Method is called from another method in the ServiceClass named PressButton which is called from the Homecontroller. Furthermore it is called by another method in the ServiceClass named EcecuteSpeechCommand which isnt called by the HomeController

Answer (score 0):

You will get a response every time a request is made. But if the **ExecuteCommand()**
is triggered from another service, the current Request value won´t be pushed to FRONT until a new request is made.

If the request is the one triggering **ExecuteCommand**, this example could work: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5mVvb9

If not, I suggest you to use **[Regular Polling](https://javascript.info/long-polling#regular-polling)**. With this approach, you could make periocal request to the BACKEND and check for the new **Request** value.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your fast answer to my question. Just to make sure you got me right: the ExecuteCommand(); is called when the keyword of the recognition is spoken (like "Hey Google") and then the answer to my request is generated. I want the answer and my speech request to be shown in the box without clicking a button. Is Regular Polling the only way? If yes could you give me a more specific example for my code. Thank you so much!

Comment: The only way to prevent Regular Polling is making a POST Request with spoken audio to backend. I think there would be a service procesing that audio and returning a string response you want to be shown in the textarea. If the full process completes in a single request before 10 seconds, then there is no need to make a polling. Otherwise, if the process takes more time or if you need another background process to work the audio, then you will need a polling strategy. 

In the first case, you will just need to POST audio to backend and capture de string response to fill textarea.